# Can we set Multiple Apple push notification settings for an App in iOS as calendar App

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to send two type of push notification in single app. 
Following is the display type.
1) Banner - One will show as banner when push arrived.
2) Alert - Second will show as alert when device unlocked.

// For more clarification go to settings>notifications and check settings for calendar app. it has different setting for upcoming event,Invitation,Invitee response etc. I want to do like this.

I am able to set the single  type setting for app and all the notification will show according to that. i try lot of methods but it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is: no.

Currently, your app can only have a single alert style. See also the [documentation on push notification payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1).

Comment: But the Calendar app doing this

Comment: But the calendar app is also a first party app (i.e. by Apple)

Comment: Can we do on anything server side so that app shows notifications as alertview.

Comment: I'm not aware of any other possibility, no.